# API to express an operation to test whether one `Predicate` is stricter than another `Predicate`?

Tags: java, guava, predicate

Is there some standard way, in Java, to express an operation to test whether one `Predicate` is stricter than another `Predicate`?

I could imagine something like `pred1.isStricterThan(pred2)`, however I don't see such thing in the APIs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html
and https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html 
.

This type of check could be useful for e.g. re-using cached search results.

I see `isEqual()` and `equals()`, which could be helpful, however there are further optimizations possible...

EDIT:

Examples:

1. `string.contains("xy")` is stricter than `string.contains("x")`
2. `string.contains("xy") && string.contains("ab")` is stricter than just `string.contains("xy")`
3. `x > 3` is stricter than `x > 2`
4. `string.contains("abc"`) is NOT stricter than `string.contains("cd")`

The strictness check methods would of course have to be cleverly implemented case-by-case.

EDIT 2&3: The stricter predicate, when used for filtering, should return a subset of the less-strict one.

EDIT 4: NOTE: I'm not asking for **implementations**. Rather, I'm asking if there is some **API** to express those checks in a standard way.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "stricter"? If you can define that clearly and precisely, an answer my be possible.

Comment: @Bohemian - I'd assume that it means that for two predicates operating on the same domain, the stricter predicate's `test()` method (for the Java version) returns `true` for a subset of the what the less strict predicate evaluates as `true`, and for nothing else.

Comment: @Bohemian: thanks, I've added 3 examples and 1 counter-example

Comment: @TedHopp: Yes. More strictly put perhaps: "strict subset" :)

Comment: @TedHopp: excuse me, the subset does not have to be **strict**. Could be equal in some cases.

Comment: No, there isn't because there isn't a sane way to test for this, certainly not with the interface provided by `Predicate`. This sort of check can't be done unless both instances know excruciating detail about each others' internals. It sort of sounds like 'can we just solve the halting problem'.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. It wasn't clear to me in which sense you meant one predicate being stricter than another.

Comment: @pvg: I think for many useful cases it is not that hard to write the implementation. E.g. for the examples I gave, it is possible. If the implementation cannot determine it, it could return `false` or `null` (if `Bool`), which would be fine.

Comment: Again, how are the 'useful cases' going to identify each other? Yes, there is conceivably some kind of implementation of `Predicate` and its potential subclasses where you might be able to have a sensible `contains` method (specifically, ones where the domain is enumerable and small) but generally, you can't.

Comment: @pvg For all the practical filtering cases that I'm implementing, there is quite an easy implementation. And it would be nice to have/write a standard API to deal with this fact.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a more specific question regarding the kind of filters you are implementing.

Comment: @pvg EDIT 4: NOTE: I'm not asking for **implementations**. Rather, I'm asking if there is some **API** to express those checks in a standard way.

Comment: No, there isn't because outside of specific cases, such checks are impossible. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: @KarolDepka There is no such API, because it would be impossible to implement in general.  You should make your own API if it's possible for the predicates you're concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)). You can use Google Guava's new [graph API](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/package-summary.html) to define a predicate strictness graph and query it:

```
Predicate<String> containsX = string -> string.contains("x");
Predicate<String> containsXy = string -> string.contains("xy");
Predicate<String> containsXyAndAb = string -> string.contains("xy") 
        && string.contains("ab");
Predicate<Integer> greaterThan2 = x -> x > 2;
Predicate<Integer> greaterThan3 = x -> x > 3;
Predicate<String> containsAbc = string -> string.contains("abc");
Predicate<String> containsCd = string -> string.contains("cd");

MutableGraph<Predicate<?>> predicateStrictnessGraph = GraphBuilder.directed().build();

predicateStrictnessGraph.addNode(containsX);
predicateStrictnessGraph.addNode(containsXy);
predicateStrictnessGraph.addNode(containsXyAndAb);
predicateStrictnessGraph.addNode(greaterThan3);
predicateStrictnessGraph.addNode(containsAbc);
predicateStrictnessGraph.addNode(containsCd);

predicateStrictnessGraph.putEdge(containsXy, containsX);
predicateStrictnessGraph.putEdge(containsXyAndAb, containsXy);
predicateStrictnessGraph.putEdge(greaterThan3, greaterThan2);

boolean isContainsXyStricterThanContainsX =
        Graphs.reachableNodes(predicateStrictnessGraph, containsXy)
                .contains(containsX);
// result: true

boolean isContainsXyStricterThanContainsXyAndAb =
        Graphs.reachableNodes(predicateStrictnessGraph, containsXy)
                .contains(containsXyAndAb);
// result: false
```

To further illustrate this consider querying the graph for predicates stricter than a specified predicate:

```
Predicate<String> containsAb = string -> string.contains("ab");
predicateStrictnessGraph.addNode(containsAb);
predicateStrictnessGraph.putEdge(containsAbc, containsAb);
predicateStrictnessGraph.putEdge(containsXyAndAb, containsAb);
Set<Predicate<?>> containsAbAndStricterPredicates =
        Graphs.reachableNodes(Graphs.transpose(predicateStrictnessGraph), containsAb);
// result: [containsAb, containsAbc, containsXyAndAb]
```

For more details, see [GraphsExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained).

Comment: This requires someone to set up a graph with all conditions in it, and there are an infinite number of conditions, so the graph would use a lot of memory.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex "The strictness check methods would of course have to be cleverly implemented case-by-case" (KarolDepka). A single code base would have to have a finite number of predicates for their strictness to be defined.

Comment: The question is about a method called `isStricterThan` that takes two instances of the `Predicate` Java class in its standard library, which allows for all predicates, not just a few. The example use of reusing cached search results doesn't make sense if you limit the possible searches to only a few examples. Very few people implement search engines that can only search for a hand-entered list of predicates.

Comment: The question is about something _like_ a method called `isStricterThan`; something "standard". A graph ADT can be used with cached search results as long as the search engine can determine the relative strictness of a given search query predicate and insert it appropriately into the graph. The graph would also need to be updated whenever results are evicted from the cache.